# Synonym for "main topic" (of a book)?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I have a book that is divided in 5 main topics. What would be a good synonym for "main topic", in a formal document?

**"Main theme"** or **"Main subject"** would be better?

Also, if I wanted to replace "main", what should I use? I want to stress how "vital" these topics are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Subject**, **theme**, **issue** are all fine synonyms of *topic* for the usage you want.

Comment: What else do you do with your day, FX_?

Comment: The pillars of great communities are great users like @FX_. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Also, if I wanted to replace "main", what should I use? I want to stress how "vital" these topics are.

Well, perhaps you could call them *vital topics*

Other possibilities include core, fundamental, important, essential, major. These are not exact synonyms so suitability depends on context.

Comment: I like "core"..